# Convert Relational Dataset to List<T>

Tags: c#, dataset, generic-list

Change Dataset to `List<Form>`

dataset has 4 table each table has relationship with other table

```
ds.Relations.Add("Form_To_Tab", ds.Tables[0].Columns["Id"],
                                       ds.Tables[1].Columns["FormId"]);
ds.Relations.Add("Tab_To_Section", ds.Tables[1].Columns["Id"],
                                       ds.Tables[2].Columns["TabId"]);
ds.Relations.Add("Section_To_Attribute", ds.Tables[2].Columns["Id"],
                                       ds.Tables[3].Columns["SectionId"]);
```

i want to create a List from database only create one `List<Form>` which is contains the data of Dataset

```
List<Form> -> List<Tab> -> List<Section> -> List<Attributes>
```

IE: Class Form has a property of `List<Tab>`, Class Tab Has a property of `List<Section>`

I have Classes of `Form, Tab, Section, Attribute`

Classes contains related datatables all columns as a property

Comment: How are the classes related ? Does 1 Form has multiple tabs ? Please post the code for Form, Tab , Section and Attributes classes.

Comment: it's somewhat painful to fully imagine your schema with just those relations.

Comment: Yes classes are related to each other  IE:Class Form has a property of List<Tab>, Class Tab Has a property of List<Section>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could recursively select all the data through the relations in the data set with something like the following:

```
        var result =
            (from form in data.Tables["form"].Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
            select
                new Form
                {
                    Tabs = 
                        (
                        from tab in form.GetChildRows("Form_To_Tab")
                        select 
                            new Tab
                            {
                                // and so on
                            }).ToList()
                }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example to convert a Datatable to a list, by selecting the columns that you want:

```
var myData = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new {
    column1 = r.Field<string>("FormId")       
});
var list = myData.ToList(); 


var myData2 = ds.Tables[1].AsEnumerable().Select(r => new {
    column1 = r.Field<string>("TabId"),

});

var list2 = myData2 .ToList();
```

Comment: i want only one object `List<Form>` which is contains all the data of dataset , please check ones i am edited my queston